# Eviar imagenes contenida en una tabla html

Tags: javascript, php

buenas necesito ayuda estoy realizando este formulario con html y javascript
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el cual despues de darle click al boton **AGREGAR** se agrega a una tabla de la siguiente forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el detalle es que no encuentro la manera de como enviar todas las imagenes que se encuentran en la tabla mediante javascript a un controlador php

aqui el codigo de la tabla

```
let empTab = document.querySelector("#table_warranty tbody");
  let rowCnt = document.getElementById("table_warranty").rows.length; // get the number of rows.
  let cont = rowCnt - 1;
  let tr = document.createElement("TR");
  let html = "";
  const imgInput = document.querySelector("#file_warranty");
  let button =
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary btn-active-color-light btn-sm deleteRow"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash fs-3"></i></button>';
  // html += "<tr>";
  html += "<td>" + cont + 1 + "</td>";
  html += "<td text-start>" + '<span class="text-dark fw-bold text-hover-primary d-block mb-1 fs-6">' + data.description + "</span>" + "</td>";

  html +=
    "<td>" +
    '<span class=" fw-semibold  d-block fs-3">Marca: ' +
    data.brand +
    "</span>" +
    '<span class=" fw-semibold  d-block fs-3">Serie: ' +
    data.serie +
    "</span>" +
    '<span class=" fw-semibold  d-block fs-3">Modelo: ' +
    data.model +
    "</span>" +
    '<span class=" fw-semibold  d-block fs-3">Color: ' +
    data.color +
    "</span>" +
    "</td>";
  html +=
    "<td>" +
    '<span class=" fw-semibold  d-block fs-4">Estado: ' +
    data.status +
    "</span>" +
    '<span class=" fw-semibold  d-block fs-4">Valor de Mercado: ' +
    data.price +
    "</span>" +
    "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + '<span class=" fw-semibold  d-block fs-4">' + data.location + "</span>" + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + '<img  class="h-75 w-75 align-self-end" src="' + URL.createObjectURL(imgInput.files[0]) + '" alt="">' + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + button + "</td>";
  // html += "</tr>";
  tr.innerHTML = html;
  empTab.appendChild(tr);
```

agradecere cualquier ayuda!!!

Comment: Puedes meter las imágenes en un `FormData` y mandarlas al servidor mediante Ajax o la nueva API Fetch. Debes decidirte por el modo de enviarlas y escribir código PHP para recuperarlas en el servidor.

Comment: yo suponia que si se podia enviar como un array pero no se como añadir el tipo file al array

Comment: Si la imagen están en tu dispositivo local la puedes meter en el FormData, si está en una URL quizá es mejor pasar esa URL y que el servidor la tome directamente de esa URL. [Lee sobre FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData). Y en [este enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#enviando_archivos_usando_objetos_formdata) puedes ver cómo enviar archivos con FormData.

Comment: el detalle es que tiene que enviar la imagen con todos los campos que aparecen en las fotos que he compartido